# laravel 7 Auth::routes don't work for disabling registration and password reset

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I've a project upgraded from laravel 5.4 to 7.6.2, everything is ok, except that I'm unable to remove registration and password reset routes from blade using has('password.request').

As per documentation, I use below options as first line inside the web.php route file:

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false, 'request' => false, 'reset' => false]);
```

the problem is that the below code is still executed:

```
@if (Route::has('password.request'))
  <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
    {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
  </a>
@endif
```

As suggested around also on stackoverflow, I also removed the ResetPasswordController.php, RegisterController.php and the ForgotPasswordController.php but after runing "composer dump" the route is still available when I call has('password.request').

Obivioulsy if I click on reset request the route don't exist and the user is unable to reset the password, but I want understand if I did it in the right way. My doubt is mostly arount has('password.request'), why return always true?

Comment: I guess you are doing something wrong because i have tried with laravel fresh installation and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, after two hour of digging... I just discovered that for some reason I had TWO different calls to Auth::routes().

The first one is mine call with all corrects parameters, the second one was at the end of the web.php route file and is empty! so I "reset" my own setting :(

I don't know how can be happen... probabily is a mistake made during the migration process from 5.4 to 7.x